# Jenkins/Hudson Build All Branches With Prioritization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

How do I configure Jenkins to build all branches while giving the master branch the highest priority?

My first idea was to create two jobs with one configured to build all branches and the other to just build master, then using the job priority plugin to configure master ahead.

This doesn't work since all branches obviously builds all branches including master.

Comment: Well your idea would work, just you would build master twice when it changes. Otherwise, probably the only other solution is if your non-master branches have a certain prefix, like "feature/".

Comment: So anything with a `namespace/` doesn't get built by `**` from Jenkins?

Comment: It does get build. I meant that if you have `master` and your other branches under `namespace/` (or any other prefix, doesn't have to include a `/`), you could set `namespace/**` as your branch specifier.

Comment: I'm looking for something that just a _little_ more elegant.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/45

Comment: Christ on a cracker you are a genius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git plugin has the BuildChooser extension point for this kind of purposes. Git plugin tells you all the interesting revisions that you might want to build (new tip commits that haven't been built before), and BuildChooser gets to decide which revision gets built.

So if your BuildChooser always prefer to build the mater, you get the desired semantics.

Comment: Did some quick research on BuildChooser. I have the git plugin installed for Jenkins, but I'm not sure how to do what I described since I can't find any documentation on BuildChooser.

Comment: @Maletor: You need to write a Jenkins plugin with a "`EverythingButMasterBuildChooser`" class which extends `BuildChooser` (see the default implemenation for reference http://is.gd/hiWvtQ).

Answer (score 0):

[Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234938/christopher) solved my question by [writing the functionality](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/45).

Give this guy some karma.