# How do I configure Jenkins to build all branches except a few which I exclude?

Tags: regex, git, jenkins

We have some code in git and I started setting up Jenkins to grab our branches and try a compile.  It seems that a few of the branches may have begun to rot in the years since they were last built, as they fail to finish a make.

I would like to build all branches that are found, except for a list of excluded ones.  Is this possible in Jenkins?  This will let me get things up and running, then come back to enable more branches as I try to fix them.

**What I have tried so far**

*Regex with lookahead*

Looking at the 'Git > Branches to build' option I was hopeful that I could replace the default '**' wildcard with a :.  A bit of digging about and double checking with http://rubular.com/ suggested that the following might do what I wanted.

:^(?!origin/exclude\-this\-branch\.v1|origin/exclude\-this\-branch\-too.v2)(\S+)

Now there is an assumption here about the regex engine running in the background.  I would hope it might understand lookahead, but if it does not that explains why this method fails.  It seems to build all the branches, including the one I am try to exclude.  Maybe I just need to find some more debug?

*Looked for similar questions here*

I came across [Jenkins/Hudson Build All Branches With Prioritization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518392/jenkins-hudson-build-all-branches-with-prioritization) which seemed to contain a possible solution in that some added an *inverse* option to branch matching https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/45 sounds like what I need.  Sadly this does not seem to be in the version of Jenkins I have, which is odd as 2011 is a long time ago.

**The System I Am Using**

Ubuntu LTS 14.04.  Jenkins ver. 1.611.  GNU tool chains to make C/C++ code.

Comment: This is pretty much a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314632/how-to-exclude-git-branch-from-building-in-jenkins). You should write a regex that *matches* only the branches you want to exclude (or simpler would be to add multiple "Branch to build" entries), and then use the "Inverse" choosing strategy.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr that sounds like the solution I need.  I just could not find out where the inverse options was hidden.  I have tried it out and it seems to not work, still tries to build the excluded branch but I will persist.  Should you put your comment as an answer so that I can select it or is that not how duplicates are handled?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using

```
^(?!.*master).*$
```

as branch specifier. This regexp means all branches not matching master.

Breakdown:

```
^(?!.*master).*$
^                ---> beginning of string
 (?!        )    ---> negative lookahead find all that doesnt match
    .*           ---> zero or more of 'any' character
      master     ---> should not match master
             .*$ ---> will match anything to the end of string
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709097/109305

Comment: I stated in the question that I had tried this and it was not working.  Maybe the RegEx engine has been updated in the past two years so that it works now.  I ended up doing the Inverse choosing strategy as suggested by ChristopherOrr.

Comment: how to use ignore for two branches such a master and feature branches

Comment: Often, look-ahead (or look-behind) assertions only work with fixed-length strings.  Also, in this particular case I believe that you cannot use '|' to combine the things you want to exclude - instead, you must define multiple negative look-ahead assertions in a row.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078924/2773846

Comment: so if i take out ?!, then it will match any branches containing master?

Answer (score 10):

I needed using the Jenkins tool "filter branch by regex", and I discovered flavor of that regex works just with back reference.
So, following the [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109305/jesper-r%C3%B8nn-jensen) response and [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36141), here I did two more examples:

```
^(?:.*release\/\d+.\d+.\d+(?!.))$
// check all branches like "release/0.0.0" or "origin/release/1.2.3"
^(?:.*release\/\d+.\d+.\d+_any)$
// check all branches like "release/0.0.0_any" or "origin/release/1.2.3_any"
```

I hope this would helpful for someone

**EDIT - [New example](https://regex101.com/r/Y81tJC/4)**

```
^(?:origin\/develop|origin\/master|origin\/release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?!.)|origin\/release\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:_uat|_preprod))$
```

or

```
^(?:.*develop|.*master|.*release/\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?!.))$
```

Comment: What is the purpose of those `?:` parts? Shouldn't the first regex simple be `^.*release\/\d+.\d+.\d+$`?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I give you the code grant where I'm using those regexes:
`triggers { gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: false, branchFilterType: "RegexBasedFilter", targetBranchRegex: '^(?:(?!feature).)*$') }`
if you don't use it, that trigger doesn't work.