# Ignore old releases in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to migrate an old project to Jenkins. It already had a couple of release which I don't want to (and sometimes can't - don't ask) build.

So basically, how can I tell Jenkins to build anything matching Git branches `releases/1.10` and following, ignoring `releases/0.1` up to `releases/1.9.1`?

One option would be to tell Jenkins "you have seen+built these branches" - something which Jenkins remembers automatically if you tell it to build "release/*" - it will build "release/1.0" only when someone pushed something new to that branch.

Comment: releases is a folder on Jenkins ? Specify more details.. it is not clear

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095583/how-do-i-configure-jenkins-to-build-all-branches-except-a-few-which-i-exclude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach with some manual work is to create regexp patterns which match only new versions. In the case above, this would work:

```
:releases/1.\d\d+.*
```

This matches anything with a two digit minor version (so 1.0 .. 1.9 or excluded). Note the colon at the beginning tells Jenkins to treat this as a regexp.

It will break when you start with 2.x but you can either add a second branch in the Jenkins UI with the pattern `release/2*` (no colon here!) or use a more complex regexp:

```
:releases/(1.\d\d+|[2-9]).*
```

Things are more complicated if you want to start with 1.5:

```
:releases/(1.[5-9]|1.\d\d+|[2-9]).*
```

Read: `1.` followed by 5 to 9 OR `1.` followed by at least two digits (1.10, 1.11, ..., 1.20 ...) OR starting with 2 to 9.